# Orika mapping field to default or fixed value

Tags: java, mapping, pojo, orika

What are my options for mapping a field missing from the source source class to a default value for a field in my destination class?

I have something like:

```
public class MySource {
  private String name;
}

public class MyDest {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Since the 'age' field in MyDest doesn't have a corresponding field in MySource I'd like to insert a default value via the Orika mapping.

NOTE: I don't have the ability to change the class definition for MySource or MyDest

Comment: What constructors are available?

Comment: Can you also post all getters/setters? I ask because Orika cannot map `private` fields without getters and setters/constructors.

Comment: Sorry, the example above is contrived.  Both the source class and destination class have public setter & getters for each attribute and both have no-arg constructors.

Comment: Have you found a solution?